# Ogr2ogr unable to export S57's Symbol to Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, kml, ogr2ogr

I am using ogr2ogr tool to convert the S57 files to shapefile. However in the resulted shapefile, I am unable to show the original icons from the S57. For example, the SOUNDG layer be represented by number (depth), but my shapefile just shows a circles when imported to Arcgis map.

I would like to know is there any way to keep the depth information of the S57 while convert to shapefile or even kml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S57 stores both data and symbology in the same format while shapefiles only store the data. So infact the depth information is present in the shapefile, what is missing are the instructions to display that number as text and a dot (or whatever S57 uses for depth points) - thus ArcMap or QGis will just display the point by default. You will need to add some styling information to tell the program to display a text label (based on the depth value) next to the point.

Comment: Hi iant, Thank very much for you answer. I will find a way to add the styling information. Meanwhile, I use a "dirty" way to show it via exporting the layer to the KML and have some "massage" to the KML. Again thanks iant.